# Distribution of negative charges in iodine dioxide difluoride anion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrons, lewis-structure

I was drawing the structure for $\ce{[IO2F2]-}.$ I'm stuck on whether the negative charge should be given to oxygen or iodine.

Comment: Have you tried both? What looks more feasible to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compound for which the V.S.E.P.R. diagram is asked for is $\ce{[IO2F2]-}$

As OP has stated, there are two possibilities for the negative charge.

- One, we add the negative charge to an oxygen atom. In such a scenario, we would have three different types of connected groups: $\ce{O-}$, $\ce{O}$, $\ce{F}$.
- Second, we give the negative charge to the iodine (central atom), In such a scenario, we would have two types of connected groups: $\ce{O}$, $\ce{F}$ . We also have $8$ electrons in the central atom whereas in the first case, we have seven.

---

#### Oxygen gets the electron

Here, the electrons of iodine would be distributed in the following way to complete the octet of the connected groups: $1$ electron to $\ce{O-}$, $2$ electrons($1$ for a sigma bond and one for the pi bond) to $\ce{O}$ and $1$ electron to each fluorine. This leaves the iodine with one lone pair.

Therefore, according to VSEPR, we have $4$ sigma bonds, $1$ lone pair. Which is equivalent to a see-saw shape with the fluorines at the axial position.

#### Iodine gets the electron

Here, the electrons of iodine would be distributed in the following way to complete the octet of the connected groups: $2$ electrons each(one for a sigma bond and one for the pi bond) to both oxygen atoms and $1$ electron to each fluorine. This leaves the iodine with one lone pair.

Therefore, according to VSEPR, we have $4$ sigma bonds, $1$ lone pair. Which is equivalent to a see-saw shape with the fluorines at the axial position.

---

As you can see both cases have identical geometries and no change in positions of atoms. This is because both of them are resonance structures of each other. **Both are correct.**

Comment: I got the core answer but u said that the structures are resonance structures of each other plz confirm that its bcuz the oxygen gives a coordinate bond to the d subshell in case if oxygen gets the electron